# Equation of a specific shape's edge?

Tags: geometry, curves

Suppose we have such a shape:
[image]
It is needed to found what this shape's edges are.

I mean, this shape edges are:

- outer arc (upper) - we know everything we would like about this arc: radius, start and end angles, start and end points, center point – everything.
- bottom straight line - we know everything we would like about this line too: start and end point
- right straight line - we know everything we would like about this line too: start and end point.
- inner arc (lower) - some kind of curve

I cannot understand, or solve, what kind of a curve this inner arc is. Seems like it is a arc, at first look. But at the second, seems like this is a spiral, but I can't prove this...

I would like to get exact equation or parametrization of this curve.

Could you help me with this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: In a first approximation, suppose, that angle of an outer-arc is between 0 and 90 degrees. In the general case this angle can be between 0 and 360 degrees. Lower straight line is always horizontal, 'right' line is always parallel to the radius of an outer-arc.

**UPD:** 
Sorry, for misleading, forgot about the main.

This shape is just like a part of a ring with different thickness. We know startThickness and endThickness (lengths of a segments – left straight line and right straight line).
We can choose any angle, cut this 'ring' by a radius at this angle - and the thickness in this cut, should be:
`thickness = startThickness + (endThickness - startThickness) * cutAngle/ fullAngle`.
So thickness is grown linear from start to end.

So, this image is just like a demonstration, it shows the idea. I don't have task to work with this image.

Comment: "seems like a spiral, but I can't prove this" - Is tis low-resolution image all you have?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry, I forgot about the main condition. Please, take a look, I updated the question

Comment: Is it really fullAngle/cutAngle instead of cutAngle/fullAngle? If it is the second case, the curve has the form $r = a + b\theta$ in polar coordinates. It is known as an [Archimedean spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral).

Comment: @achillehui thank you for your comment. This was a mistake, of course.. I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, like I found part of the solution.
In polar coordinates we can describe arc like this:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\rho=R \\ 
\theta=\alpha_1+\alpha_2 t
\end{array}
\right.
,t \in [\alpha_1, \alpha_1+\alpha_2]
$$ where $\alpha_1$ – start angle, $\alpha_2$ – full arc angle

And the bottom curve, (based on the:
$thickness=a+ (b- a)\alpha_2/ \beta$
where $\beta$ is a cut angle, $a$ - start thickness, $b$ - end thickness)
has this system as a parametrization.
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\rho=R-a - (b-a) t \\ 
\theta=\alpha_1+\alpha_2 t
\end{array}
\right.
,t \in [\alpha_1, \alpha_1+\alpha_2]
$$

But I still don't know what kind of a curve this parametrization describes.
Next step I should translate this system to Cartesian coordinate system, using:
$\rho^2=x^2+y^2$
$\theta=atan2(y, x)$

Reference: [Polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). Look at 'Converting between polar and Cartesian coordinates' section

**UPD:**
OK, got it, thanks to @achillehui for hint about Archimedean spiral.
From this system:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\rho=R-a - (b-a) t \\ 
\theta=\alpha_1+\alpha_2 t
\end{array}
\right.
,t \in [\alpha_1, \alpha_1+\alpha_2]
$$

we can find:
$t=(\theta-\alpha_1)/\alpha_2$
and then:
$\rho(\theta)=R-a - (b-a) (\theta-\alpha_1)/\alpha_2$

**UPD 2:**

In Cartesian coordinate system:
$x=\rho \cos\theta$
$y=\rho \sin\theta$

So, in this case:
$x(\theta)=(R-a - (b-a) (\theta-\alpha_1)/\alpha_2)\cos\theta$
$y(\theta)=(R-a - (b-a) (\theta-\alpha_1)/\alpha_2)\sin\theta$
$\theta\in[\alpha_1, \alpha_1+\alpha_2]$